# How to enter the correct format to view vehicle emissions?

Tags: sumo

I want to see the emissions data of the vehicle during the simulation after the simulation ends, but it may be that the format I imported is wrong, and the simulation cannot run. If you can, can you give me a screenshot of the actual example, which is convenient for me to compare. Thank you!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwPMP.png)

Answer (score 0):

The problem shown in the image is a much more basic one. The variable exp you use is not known. You may want to read some introductory lessons on python before diving into sumo.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice, I have solved this problem.